# Using Python , Selenium webdriver click() method is not working

Tags: python, selenium, click

I'm using selenium 4 with python to automate webpage.
Click() method is not working.
Able to click a button using submit() method only if the path has type=submit, but couldnt able to select a link using click method. Please help if anyone knows alternative option for click() method to click a link.

The following is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s = Service("C:/Program Files/webdriver/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("https://www.sololearn.com/users/login")
time.sleep(2)

#driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sl-login-login-form").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#---click here fails--------
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sl-login-login-form").click()
#---click here fails
#driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sl-login-login-form").submit()
#login.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()

**Also i have tried with the below code but still it is not working:**

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sl-login-login-form").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sl-login-login-form").submit()
login.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "CLASSNAME")))

element.click();
```

OR

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "className")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

***Do not forget to import***

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
```

Comment: @Sunila S - Please accept the answer if this has solved your issue.